# move subtree from one part of AST to another

Tags: antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a tool to convert Oracle SQL to ANSI SQL. I have a grammar that will parse both Oracle SQL and ANSI SQL.

I want to extract the Oracle outer join expressions from the where clause part of the AST and insert new join clauses at the end of the from clause part of the AST for the matching select or subquery.

Can a tree parser with rewrite rules do this type of tree transformation?

i.e. take an AST generated from Oracle SQL

```
SELECT
  a.columna, b.columnb
FROM
  tablea a,
  tableb b
WHERE
  a.columna2 (+) = b.columnb2 (+)
  AND
  a.columna3 = 'foo'
  AND
  b.columnb3 = 'bar'
```

and transform it to an AST for ANSI SQL

```
SELECT
  a.columna, b.columnb
FROM
  tablea a FULL OUTER JOIN tableb b ON (a.columna2 = b.columnb2 )
WHERE
  a.columna3 = 'foo'
  and
  b.columnb3 = 'bar'
```

NOTE1: the table references for `tablea` and `tableb` are deleted from the `FROM` clause and replaced with a `JOIN` clause referring to the same tables and table aliases.

NOTE2: the Oracle join condition is identified as a `FULL OUTER JOIN` by the presence of the OuterJoinIndicator (+) on both sides of the sql_condition comparison.

NOTE3: the join condition comparison is deleted from the `WHERE` clause and used to construct the join clause ON condition [with the OuterJoinIndicator(s) removed].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is quite possible, especially since you have a grammar that recognizes both Oracle and ANSI SQL.  I once wrote a translator from AREV BASIC to Visual BASIC and did many similar transformations.

In my project I used ANTLR 2 and wrote a master tree grammar which did nothing but completely walk the tree according to all rules in my grammars.  I then used ANTLR 2's subclassing to override specific rules to do the transformations.  I liked this as it let me build up the translation in passes and keep all my expression handling in one pass, control structures in another pass, etc.

ANTLR 3 does not provide grammar subclassing, so you won't be able to use that approach.  You will need a complete tree grammar to print out your resulting tree.  Personally, I would write that tree grammar first and get it working properly.  Then I would copy that grammar and strip all the actions out but put in the option to rewrite the AST.  Then modify the rules you need for your transformation.  If you do many transformations you may want to use multiple passes, one tree grammar for each pass.  You may have a pass or two that does analysis to help drive the later passes.  On my BASIC translation project I did control flow analysis, data flow analysis and dead code removal as analysis passes.

If you want help writing the specific transformation you'll need to share your tree grammar.  There are quite a few tree grammar idioms to wrap your head around.  Terence's ANTLR 3 book would be a valuable purchase if you need help there.  If you haven't written the tree grammar yet then post questions when you get stuck.  Choosing the correct root nodes is important.  If you want to get an idea of how to build trees and tree parsers, you can look at my C grammar.  It is ANTLR 2, but the tree building concepts are the same.  http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/cgram/grammars/

Do you need to retain comments and formatting?  That adds another layer of complexity, for which I would recommend creating another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different grammars, you are likely to discover that the "small differences" in the grammars lead to quite considerably different ASTs for these clauses, and so your real problem is to convert the tree structure for one into the tree structure for another.   And you'll have to do this piecewise for the *whole tree* because such differences are spread all across the grammars.  YMMV.

ANTLR's tree parser will pretty likely let you *recognize* arbitrary fragments; these are certainly cues for generating equivalents in the other grammar's AST.   But you'll have to write lots of such fragments, and the code corresponding routines to assemble the equivalent tree node-by-node.  As a general rule for a large grammar (such as Oracle SQL), this can be quite a lot of work.  You can do it this way.

An alternative is [program transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) systems.  These are tools that allow you to write surface syntax patterns (e.g., phrases in Oracle SQL and ANSI SQL) to code and apply your transformations directly.  Writing transformations this way is considerably easier IMHO.   You'd end up writing something like this:

```
 source domain Oracle.
 target domain ANSISQL.
 rule xlate_Oracle_SELECT(c: columns, t1: table, t2: table,
                          c1: column, c2: column,
                          more_conditions: conditions):SQL_phrase
     "SELECT \c FROM \t1, \t2 WHERE c1 (+) = c2 (+) and \more_conditions";
  =>
      "SELECT \c FROM  \t1 FULL OUTER JOIN \t2 on ( c1 = c2 ) WHERE \more_conditions";
```

(The backslash-IDs are pattern variables which can match an arbitrary subtree of the the declared syntax type legal in that location.)

The reason this works is that the transformation tool parses the first pattern with the first grammar, and so gets a tree it can match on trees of the first grammar, and similarly parses the second pattern using the *second* grammar, getting a replacement tree that follows the rules of the second grammar. The transformation engine matches the tree for first pattern, and substitutes the tree for the second.    So such a rule transforms a small set of blue tree nodes from the blue tree, to a small set of green nodes of the desired tree type.  The color analogy should make it clear that you have to translate *all* the blue nodes into green ones if you want an accurate translation.

You'd need additional rules to translate the various subclauses just to paper over the differences in the grammar, e.g.,:

```
rule translate column(t: IDENTIFIER, c: IDENTIFIER, ):table->table
    "\t.\c" -> " \toSQLidentifier\(\t\).\toSQLidentifier\(\c\)";
```

This would handles differences in how the two languages spell identifiers, by calling a custom function *toSQLidentifier* that does string hacking.

I don't think ANTLR supports these kind of transformation rules.  You can simulate it all by lots of code.

You might avoid some of this if you have one "union" grammar for both languages (which is what you imply), but this usually gets you a highly ambiguous grammar and that's a huge amount of trouble. If you have succeeded in this, than you only have to apply translation rules where the languages differ (e.g., everything is a blue node).

You can also hack it:  scan the tree left to right; prettyprint the parts that are equivalent (figuring this out is harder than it looks), where they differ, prettyprint a substitution.  This is a very fragile way to do this.

Comment: There is only 1 grammar that parses Oracle SQL and all of the ANSI SQL syntax that we require.

Comment: The grammar recognizes the cases of sql_condition that need to be handled and adds "tags" that can be searched for by token type.

Comment: condition_comparison
    :
    ( ( column_reference OuterJoinSign relop column_reference OuterJoinSign ) =>
       col1a=column_reference oj1a=OuterJoinSign rop1=relop col1b=column_reference oj1b=OuterJoinSign
       -> ^( 't_full_join_condition' $col1a $oj1a $rop1 $col1b $oj1b )
    
    | ( column_reference OuterJoinSign relop column_reference ) =>
       col2a=column_reference oj2a=OuterJoinSign rop2=relop col2b=column_reference 
       -> ^( 't_right_join_condition' $col2a $oj2a $rop2 $col2b )

Comment: I regenerate the ANSI SQL by pretty printing the AST after transformation.